# Sessions: Getting Page2.php to display 404 Error on Refresh

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to set the session with Page1.php, redirect to Page2.php, and then if Page2.php is refreshed, closed, revisited i want it to display a 404 error.  This is what I have:

page1.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['time'] = 'time';
header('location: page2.php');
exit;
```

page2.php:

```
session_start();

if( !isset( $_SESSION['time'] ) ) {
    header("Location:http://google.com");
} else {
    echo ( "this session is ". $_SESSION['time'] );
}
```

How do I add the function so page2.php expires if refreshed? I just want the page2.php url to expire for the user after the browser session ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to expire the session, do that with session_destroy()

and finally call

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

In a nutshell, once you start a session with session_start(); you will be able to access the session variables stored in $_SESSION.

And when you are done with the session, call the session_destroy() to clean up and kill the session.

for eg:

```
if($action =='logout') {
    session_destroy();
}
```

PS: if you have set session.auto_start in your php.ini configuration, you dont have to call session_start() at the top of the page.

For more information on session_destroy, follow this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

For full details on session: 
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php

Comment: how do i add the session_destroy()? never really dealt with sessions before yesterday

Answer (score 0):

add

```
$_SESSION['time'] = '';
```

at the end of else